# How to restart JS function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script for "like" button. When I am clicking to button, AJAX sending data to **videolike.php**

1. First I am getting videos from database using PHP with **limit 10**
2. After this is loading this script...

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".vidlike").click(function() {
        var form = $(this).closest(".vidlikform");

        $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: "functions/videolike.php",
             data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
             success: function(data)
             {
                 alert(data); // show response from the php script.
             } 
        });
        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
   });
   </script>
   ```

Now I have 10 videos in my HOME page, The script is working fine. Sending data to **videolike.php** without redirecting...

The problem is this script is working only for first 10 videos, 'its  not working for next videos i got from database, redirecting me to **videolike.php**...

This is the script I am using for get more data:

```
<img class="load-more" id="<?php echo @$var['video_id']; ?>" src="img/loader.gif"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Ajax more data load Home page
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('id');
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && lastID != 0){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'functions/getData.php',
                    data:'id='+lastID,
                    beforeSend:function(html){
                        $('.load-more').show();
                    },
                    success:function(html){
                        $('.load-more').remove();
                        $('#main').append(html);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: $(".vidlike").on("click",.. should be $(window).on("click",".vidlike",..

Comment: you can add normal `onclick function()` instead of jquery click event, because those are only rendered on page load.

Comment: You need to modify your php script to handle pagination, in other words, getting ids with offset.

Comment: @Jonasw I tryed but not working. Redirecting the page to **videolike.php**

Comment: @Anuga do you have an idea how to make this :)

Comment: look into pub/sub design pattern then you can broadcast events to functions which listen for updates, you can then re-apply event handlers onto the DOM which has been loaded via ajax. or just repeat your "click" code within the callback of your "scroll" code.

Comment: @halid96 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Yes I can, include your getData.php script in your question.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik I tryed to add but not working :)

Comment: @Anuga I tryed this already, its working but 2 times, becouse its included 2 times..

Comment: Actually guys i think the problem is not in **getData.php** or **GetData JS** , After I fetch 10 videos with PHP, the **like** script is working only for first 10, becouse the next 10 videos i got from database are included after **like** script... I think i need to reload/refresh my function maybe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a delegated event handler.

This will attach a single listener, and compares the clicked target against the selector, in this case `.vidlike`.

This will work even if you modify the DOM by adding more results.

```
$('body').on("click", ".vidlike", function() {
     var form = $(this).closest(".vidlikform");

     $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: "functions/videolike.php",
          data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
          success: function(data)
          {
              alert(data); // show response from the php script.
          } 
     });
     return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

See the docs for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more info.

Comment: @halid96 If this solved your problem, then click the gray checkmark on the left of my answer so it turns green :)